# onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type MapView

Tags: android, eclipse

If have the following two lines in my onCreateView of a fragment:

```
   mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapv); 
   mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

but the compiler complains about the second line, saying:

```
onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type MapView
```

How can this be?

EDIT: FYI, I also have this earlier in the code...

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `onCreate` method only exists in version 2 of the maps API `MapView`. I had accidentally added the wrong import (`com.google.android.maps.MapView` corresponds to version 1).

Answer (score 3):

> How can this be?

Because there is no `onCreate()` method on `MapView`. You can tell this by reading [the documentation for `MapView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html).

Also, please note that you are using the Maps V1 version of `MapView`, and Maps V1 has been deprecated. You may wish to consider switching to [Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for future development.

Comment: Don't you really mean there is no onCreate in MapView in API V1, the [API V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) shows an onCreate

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: The OP's list of imports shows that the OP is using `MapView` from Maps V1. That's why I linked to the Maps V1 documentation for `MapView` and pointed out that the OP is using the Maps V1 version of `MapView`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I was considering a future reader of this question who might be confused between version 1 and version 2 of the MAP API.

Comment: Can I just swap the import used to something else and be using v2 instead of v1, or isn't it that simple?

Comment: @Mick: If your objective was to use Maps V2 all along, you have the wrong import for `MapView`. It should be `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`.

Comment: I did indeed think I was using v2.